# How to make white stroke show up for a shirt printing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, background, stroke

hoping you can help me today. I think my question is very simple. I have almost no experience with Adobe, but I am trying to finish up a Christmas present...

I am making a digital file for a shirt printing company to embroider, but can't get the white stroke I made around black text in InDesign to show up against the white background.

Here is what the shirt should look like:

[image: Badman example t-shirt printing with white stroke]

http://www.spreadshirt.com/badman-t-shirts-C3376A14883793

In my file, the stroke looks right if I have it a different color. However, the stroke is not visible in an exported jpeg because of the white background in the jpeg.

How can I make the background go away so I just have the black text and white stroke?

Been sorting through lots of help online and nothing seems to help.

Comment: You simply can not have a jpg with a transparent background. JPGs do not support transparency. Why do you need a jpg if you're working in Illustrator?

Comment: Well, I just need to submit a picture formatted file to the company to print the shirt. Would the png make only the white stroke and the black text show up?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using a particular web service and their personalized requirements and needs. Answers, while they may be helpful, may only relate to the specific service being used. In short, this amounts to tech support for spreadshirt.

Answer (score 1):

Based on *that* particular service, you need to visit their requirements for image uploads and vector files: **[FOUND HERE](http://www.spreadshirt.com/help-C1328/categoryId/46/articleId/35)**

They provide templates for CorelDraw and Adobe Illustrator. You should use their template and upload the file format they request.

Their FAQ page states "We support these data formats: .svg, .ai, .eps and .cdr." There's no reason you need a jpg OR a png. Simply save your .ai file appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Save it as a .png, this file type supports image transparency, whereas .jpg does not.

Also, Illustrator is more geared toward this kind of thing, InDesign is more built for working with large amounts of text (like creating book layouts).

Answer (score -1):

The best way to create graphic Use Png images, first of all create images with photoshop and with CMYK mode, Open with this page on Illustrator and create 
i think i will help you more

at 
http://www.ownow.com

Comment: Hi Sohail, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!